# How to return x y coordinates of the selection box in Plotly JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I would like to retrieve the coordinates generated by `Box Select` from a chart made with [Plotly JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/), but looking in the documentation it seems there is no attribute for the `layout.selections.path`, how can I retrieve the `x.min`, `x.max`, `y.min` and `y.max` coordinates of a selection box?

Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#select-event) might be a good starting point. when i have some time later, i'd be happy to circle back and add an answer as well

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I figure it out how to get the coordinates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came to a solution, using a callback function of the event `plotly_selected`:

```
graphDiv.on("plotly_selected", function (d) {
    console.log(d.range);
});
```

The full code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/drypatrick/pen/jOvbypp)