# How to return x y coordinates of the cursor in Plotly JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I would like to retrieve the coordinates from the cursor hovering a chart made with [Plotly JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/), but looking in the documentation I've only found reference about hovering points of the chart, but I would like to catch information about the cursor, any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return x y coordinates of the selection box in Plotly JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495239/how-to-return-x-y-coordinates-of-the-selection-box-in-plotly-javascript)

Comment: I've asked that question :D but in this case I would like to retrieve the cursor position when hovering the chart, I don't know if an event is triggered and if so what event is it.